# Prove $a-b$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n\in\Bbb{N}^{>1}$,$P_n$# is the product of the first $n$ primes,$P_n$ is $nth$ prime number.Suppose $a$ and $b$ are coprime, and $a*b$ is multiple of $P_n$#  and $\sqrt{a-b}<P_n$ ,then $a-b$ is prime.

[A Formula for Prime Numbers?](http://www.parabola.unsw.edu.au/vol12_no3/vol12_no3_2.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sqrt{a-b} \le p_n\ $ so $\,a\!-\!b,\,$ if composite,  has a prime factor $\,p \le p_n.\,$ So $\,p\mid P_n^{\#}\mid ab,\,$ so $\,p\mid a\,$ or $\,b,\,$ hence also the other, $ $ by $\ p\mid a-b.\,$ Therefore $\ p\mid a,b,\,$ contra hypothesis $\,\color{#c00}{(a,b) = 1.}$

Or, more conceptually, by Euclid's Lemma $\,(a\!-\!b,ab)=1\,$ by  $\,(a\!-\!b,a)=\color{#c00}{(a,b)}=(a\!-\!b,b).\,$ Therefore $\,a\!-\!b\,$ is also coprime to the factor $\,P_n^{\#}\,$ of $\,ab,\,$ so $\,a\!-\!b\,$ has no prime factor $\le p_n.$

Answer (score 3):

While true, it is not *at all* useful.  $P_n\#$ is enormous compared to $P_n$ and you need $\sqrt{a-b} \lt P_n$.  If you know $P_n\#$, which entails knowing all the primes up to $P_n$, you already know $a-b$ is prime.